# Raising custom errors in procedural python scripts

Tags: python, pandas, exception

I'm putting together a short data analysis script using pandas and writing the results out to an excel sheet with graphs.

Currently I'm using `sys.exit` to make the user aware of problems associated with the input data.

Below is an example :

```
if len(titles) != len(plot_key):
    raise sys.exit('Error: Number of chart titles does not equal the number of plots to be generated')
```

In one case I'd like to share more information stored in a variable with the user

```
if df[df.Well > 3].empty is False:
    sys.exit('Error: Data contains more than 3 wells.')
```

If the condition is `True` and there are values in `df[df.Well > 3]` I'd like to share the indices of `df[df.Well > 3]` with the user so they know where the problem exists, rather then leaving it up to them to figure out.

Right now I'm doing this, but it seems like a hack.

```
if df[df.Well > 3].empty is False:
    print df[df.Well > 3].index.get_values()
    sys.exit('Error: Data contains more than 3 wells.')
```

Any suggestions on best practices would greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can create new class which extends from `Exception` class and in `__init__` or `__str__` methods you can pass your data. Or you can `raise Exception("your output")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pythonic way to raise custom errors is to define your own exceptions.  This might look something like:

```
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    pass

class ChartTitles(MyCustomException):
    pass

class TooManyWells(MyCustomException):
    pass

if len(titles) != len(plot_key):
    raise ChartTitles(
        'Number of chart titles does not equal the number of plots to be generated')      

if not df[df.Well > 3].empty:
    raise TooManyWells(
        "Data contains more than 3 wells '%s'" % df[df.Well > 3].index.get_values())
```

Basing all of your custom exceptions on one base custom exception makes it easier to catch all of your exceptions.

Comment: This finally makes sense to me.  I've read 100 "tutorials" on exceptions online I it never clicked.  Only question is this still the preferred method in less object oriented scripts?

Comment: I do not believe that exceptions are OO or not OO.

Comment: Doesn't class = OO by definition?

Comment: No, `class == object`.  And **EVERYTHING** in python is an object. OO is Object Orientated.  You can *use* objects in a non OO way (ie procedurally).

Comment: Humm. Ok. I think that makes sense.  Getting off topic but an object is just an instance of a class, right?

Comment: Yes, object is generally an instantiated class.

Comment: Guess the long and short is there really isn't procedural in python.  You can obscure the OO nature of it but it's OO at its root

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133915/discussion-between-agf1997-and-stephen-rauch).